# React - Redux on page calculation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I am getting data from API with react-redux. What I would like to do is load data, then do some calculation and the result display on the page. Right now if I load the data on the first time it wont display them, but on second load it does display them.

So I would like to wait till the computation is done and them display the number.

Structure of the store is:

```
calcs:
     loading - boolean
     arr:
        {
           number: x,
           id: x,
        }..
```

code:

```
const [result, setResult] = useState(0)
const calcs = useSelector(state=>state.calcs)
const {arr, loading} = calcs

useEffect(()=>{
   dispatch(getCalcs())
   sum()
},[])

const sum = () => {
   let sum = 0
   calcs && calcs.map(array => (
       array.map(item => {
          sum = sum + item.number
       })
   ))
   setResult(sum)
}

return(
  <div>{loading ? result : null}</div>
)
```

Comment: you may use conditional rendering like this: <div>{result? result: "" }</div>.Even you can use some loading component if you wish

Comment: @SowmiyaP It did not help, on first render there is not value displayed.If I go back and then return on the page then the number is rendered.

Comment: do you use any api call in dispatch action ?.

Comment: Yes I do, I get the data to the redux store, that is fine. I figured it out now. I used another useEffect which calls `sums` function and to the dependancy array I inserted `loading`

Comment: Could you please add full code?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out now. I used another useEffect which calls sums function and to the dependancy array I inserted loading.:

```
const [result, setResult] = useState(0)
const calcs = useSelector(state=>state.calcs) 
const {arr, loading} = calcs

useEffect(()=>{
   dispatch(getCalcs())
},[])

useEffect(()=>{
  sum()
},[loading])

const sum = () => {
   let sum = 0
   calcs && calcs.map(array => (
      array.map(item => {
         sum = sum + item.number
       })
   ))
    setResult(sum)
}

return(
  <div>{loading ? result : null}</div>
)
```